# Scrub Lucene search terms with the Standard Analyzer

Tags: java, lucene, compass-lucene

We are building a bool query out of search term strings to search our Lucene indexes.  I would like these strings to be analyzed with the Standard Analyzer, the analyzer we are using for our indexes.  For example, `foo-bar 1-2-3` should be broken up as `foo`, `bar`, `1-2-3` since the Lucene doc states that hyphens cause numbers to stay together but words to be tokenized.  What is the best way to do this?

Currently I am running my search term strings through a QueryParser.

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("", new StandardAnalyzer()); 
Query query = parser.parse(aSearchTermString);
```

The problem with this is that quotes are inserted.  For example, `foo-bar 1-2-3` becomes `"foo bar"`, `1-2-3`, which does not return anything because Lucene would have tokenized `foo-bar` into `foo` and `bar`.

I definitely don't want to hack this situation by removing the quotes with `replace` because I feel that I am probably missing something or doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually getting different results for `StandardAnalyzer`. Consider this code (using Lucene v4):

```
public class Tokens {

    private static void printTokens(String string, Analyzer analyzer) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Using " + analyzer.getClass().getName());
        TokenStream ts = analyzer.tokenStream("default", new StringReader(string));
        OffsetAttribute offsetAttribute = ts.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
        CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = ts.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

        while(ts.incrementToken()) {
            int startOffset = offsetAttribute.startOffset();
            int endOffset = offsetAttribute.endOffset();
            String term = charTermAttribute.toString();
            System.out.println(term + " (" + startOffset + " " + endOffset + ")");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        printTokens("foo-bar 1-2-3", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40));
        printTokens("foo-bar 1-2-3", new ClassicAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40));

        QueryParser standardQP = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40, "", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40));
        BooleanQuery q1 = (BooleanQuery) standardQP.parse("someField:(foo\\-bar\\ 1\\-2\\-3)");
        System.out.println(q1.toString() + "     # of clauses:" + q1.getClauses().length);
    }
}
```

Above prints:

```
Using org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer
foo (0 3)
bar (4 7)
1 (8 9)
2 (10 11)
3 (12 13)

Using org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.ClassicAnalyzer
foo (0 3)
bar (4 7)
1-2-3 (8 13)

someField:foo someField:bar someField:1 someField:2 someField:3     # of clauses:5
```

So above code proves that `StandardAnalyzer`, unlike for example `ClassicAnalyzer`, should be splitting `1-2-3` into different tokens - exactly as you want. For queries, you need to escape every keyword, including space, otherwise QP thinks this has a different meaning.

If you don't want to escape your query string, you can always tokenize it manually (like in `printTokens` method above), then wrap each token with a `TermQuery` and stack all TermQueries into a `BooleanQuery`.

Comment: Why is the StandardAnalyzer tokenizing `1-2-3` if the Apache doc states that StandardAnalyzer doesn't split numbers on hyphen?

Comment: Can you point me to this statement about StandardAnalyzer? What I found was that StandardAnalyzer uses StandardTokenizer which uses  [Unicode Standard Annex #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/). FWIW, I haven't investigated latter too deeply.

Comment: Sure, [here it is](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html).

Comment: Ghm, if I use hyphen(‐) with ClassicAnalyzer, I get the numeric text split into tokens but if I use minus(-), it does not split... which is even more confusing! Could well be that the Javadoc is outdated. Care to dig into Unicode Standard Annex #29?